# Iron-ajax url with String from parent element doesn't work

Tags: data-binding, polymer, computed-properties, iron-ajax

In my Polymer app, I want to read a JSON file, for this I use an  element. Part of the url is send by the parent element of the element currently using this .
My String is properly recovered, i tried to just display it and it return exactly what I want.
The problem is that if I just put the String in my url path like this :

```
<iron-ajax auto url="questions/{{path}}.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{questions}}"></iron-ajax>
```

It doesn't work, I read on other threads that the cause of this is the use of a dynamic String which can't be used in the url path, as the String is data-binded.

If I wrote the url manually it works just fine :

```
<iron-ajax auto url="questions/listQuestions.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{questions}}"></iron-ajax>
```

So I tried to compute my value to just return a String but it doesn't work either. It's has been hours of trying to come up with a solutions and research one on Internet but it just doesn't work.

Here's my code with the computed properties I tried :

```
properties: {
            path :String,

            url: {
                type: String,
                notify: true,
                computed: 'computeurl(path)'
            }
},

_acces: function(path) {
            return "questions/"+path+".json";
},

computeurl: function(path) {
            return path;
}
```

When I tried to display them like this :

```
<p><span>[[_acces(path)]] or [[url]] or [[path]]</span></p>
```

I got :

[Display computed properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9gC3.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a bind to some property like this you need to use it with `$` symbol.
Your example must have the view like this:

```
<iron-ajax auto url$="questions/{{path}}.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{questions}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Comment: I already tried it and it still doesn't work, I also tried to generate my request on my ready function like this :
`this.$.ajaxLoader.generateRequest()`

Comment: The `$` is only necessary if you're trying to bind to an attribute on an element in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do you:

```
<template>
    <iron-ajax auto
               url="[[_computeUrl(path)]]"></iron-ajax>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    properties: {
        "path": {
            type: String,
            value: function() {
                return 'listQuestions';
            }
        }
    },
    _computeUrl: function(path) {
        return 'questions/' + path + '.json';
    }

</script>
```

**Update 2017-4-26:** After reviewing your paste, you were missing the bower_component reference to `iron-ajax`; see pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/ShqzedyW.  Also listed a couple of your properties that you hadn't named, made `url` a computed property.  Check it out now.

Comment: It still doesn't work the url doesn't seems to accept a data-binded value even if I make a compute function

Comment: Does it hit the `_computeUrl` function when the element loaded?

Comment: If I try to show my `_computeUrl` in a <div> inside my element that use the <iron-ajax> it works fine.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using the element that contains the `iron-ajax`?